# Update Google Doc from local file using google API possible ? (.NET / C# / WPF)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, google-api

I am currently testing the google API. It seems promising, but I am stuck at a "simple" problem. I want to update an existing document with a local copy.

My idea was, download all google documents to a folder, using the doc-download. That works. At the next run, I check the dates, if a remote document is newer, grab it again. If the local document is newer, upload it, and replace the current online version.

I can't find a function to replace a document. There is a Upload(filename, doctitle) but this creates a new document. Does anybody know if this is possible and can point me in the correction direction. Do I have to dissect the atom feed (is the document content somewhere inside it..). The **"download / change in word / upload"** looked so nice :-)

Chris

And for anyone who is interested, its pretty simple and nice to use the API. Here is a short WPF example (without credentials, of course)

```
        var settings = new RequestSettings("GoogleDocumentsSample", _credentials);
        AllDocuments = new ObservableCollection<Document>();

        settings.AutoPaging = true;
        settings.PageSize = 10;

        service = new DocumentsService("DocListUploader");
        ((GDataRequestFactory)service.RequestFactory).KeepAlive = false;
        service.setUserCredentials(username, password);

        //force the service to authenticate
        var query = new DocumentsListQuery {NumberToRetrieve = 1};
        service.Query(query);



        var request = new DocumentsRequest(settings);


        Feed<Document> feed = request.GetEverything();
        // this takes care of paging the results in
        foreach (Document entry in feed.Entries)
        {
            AllDocuments.Add(entry);
            if (entry.Type == Document.DocumentType.Document)
            {
                var fI = new FileInfo(@"somepath" + entry.DocumentId + ".doc");

                if (!fI.Exists || fI.LastWriteTime < entry.Updated)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Download doc " + entry.DocumentId);
                    var type = Document.DownloadType.doc;
                    Stream stream = request.Download(entry, type);

                    if (fI.Exists) fI.Delete();

                    Stream file = fI.OpenWrite();

                    int nBytes = 2048;
                    int count = 0;
                    Byte[] arr = new Byte[nBytes];

                    do
                    {
                        count = stream.Read(arr, 0, nBytes);
                        file.Write(arr, 0, count);

                    } while (count > 0);
                    file.Flush();
                    file.Close();

                    stream.Close();

                    fI.CreationTimeUtc = entry.Updated;
                    fI.LastWriteTimeUtc = entry.Updated;

                }
                else
                {
                    if (entry.Updated == fI.LastWriteTime)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Document up to date " + entry.DocumentId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Local version newer {0} [LOCAL {1}] [REMOTE {2}]", entry.DocumentId, fI.LastWriteTimeUtc, entry.Updated));
                        service.UploadDocument(fI.FullName, entry.Title);

                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Docs API docs ;) you can replace the content of a document
http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UpdatingContent

Comment: "doh" - should have looked there.. Ok, but that means my "little test" becomes digging into ATOM download / changing / upload. Postponed :-) Unless anyone has a few lines of source code lying around and is willing to post them... Sadly there is no sample for updating..